# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment When doing webcam close and re-open it many time

Tags: java, webcam-capture

Hello Anyone plese help me , It am facing JRE Crash when WebCam close and re-open it up to 15 times.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000776ca365, pid=13328, tid=0x0000000000002628
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x2a365]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Share\Book Rental Management System\02.Source Code\Desktop Version\hs_err_pid13328.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: I am using sarxos.webcam.Webcam library. And if program do web cam close and re-open it many times, app is crash.

Comment: Please share the contents of `C:\Share\Book Rental Management System\02.Source Code\Desktop Version\hs_err_pid13328.log`